# Pagination on a ArrayList

Tags: grails, groovy

There are a lot of possibilities to make *pagination* with domain classes, but what about existing `ArrayList` of objects?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you use the standard [Grails `paginate` tag](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html), but in place of:

```
    [books: Book.list(params), bookCount: Book.count()]
```

Do something like:

```
    [books:list.drop(params.int('offset')?:0).take(params.int('max')?:10),
     bookCount: list.size()]
```

Comment: could grails paginate tag be used inside service?